# concatenate a string and a null character

Tags: java, null, concatenation

I am completely new to java, and I am trying to join to string together with a null character between them.

```
String header = "text 19"
String content = "this is the content"
String wholething = // this is supposed to be "text 19\0this is the content"
```

End-goal here is to take sha-1 sum of the wholething and write the wholething to a file. I have tried some google searches, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String wholething = header + '\0' + content;
```

Other ways to concatenate strings (in no particular order), each with their own particular uses:

- [String.concat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) - Essentially the same as the + operator.
- [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) - A flexible way to build a string.
- [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) - Efficient way to concatenate many strings.
- [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) - Similar to StringBuilder, but thread-safe.
- [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) - Extends Writer, compatible with stream IO functions.
- Probably a couple more here and there.

Comment: Wow, I was expecting something like converting those to byte arrays and adding them together and then converting back to string :)

Comment: Just one more thing, when I println it, there appears to be a space character where the null character should be. Is that expected? I am using netbeans.

Comment: That's fine, your console must just display null as a space, I guess. I'm not familiar with the idiosyncrasies of the NetBeans console.

Comment: If it gives you peace of mind, you can verify that the null is in there with, e.g. `for (int n = 0; n < wholething.length(); ++ n) System.out.println((int)wholething.charAt(n));`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String wholeThing = header + '\0' + content;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String wholething = header + "\0" + content;
```